# Shadowing SVG with css without unwanted border

Tags: css, svg, shadow

Here is my svg code, when i add css filter shadow
there is unwanted border shadow on the graphic, but i don't see here in snippet. doesn't anyone can tell what is going on?

[image: the result on my end]

```css
.shadow {
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8));
    fill:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:gray; height:500px;">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" width=300px class="shadow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 56.69 56.69"  xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M32.61,29.55V22.8c0-0.42-0.35-0.77-0.77-0.77h-2.53V7.13h3.21c1.22,0,3.67-2.38,3.67-5.53c0-0.42-0.35-0.77-0.77-0.77
  H22.08l-0.64,0.03c-0.41,0.02-0.73,0.36-0.73,0.77c0,2.89,2.14,5.16,2.23,5.27c0.14,0.15,0.35,0.24,0.56,0.24h4.25v14.89h-2.52
  c-0.42,0-0.77,0.35-0.77,0.77v6.74c-2.08,1.36-3.36,3.69-3.36,6.18c0,4.09,3.34,7.42,7.42,7.42s7.41-3.34,7.41-7.42
  C35.96,33.24,34.68,30.92,32.61,29.55z M23.86,5.59c-0.4-0.5-1.29-1.73-1.53-3.2h12.26c-0.31,1.89-1.69,3.09-2.1,3.2H23.86z
   M26.02,23.57h5.05v5.8h-5.05V23.57z M28.55,41.6c-3.24,0-5.88-2.63-5.88-5.88c0-1.92,0.96-3.71,2.52-4.8
  c0.02,0,0.03,0.01,0.05,0.01h6.6c0.02,0,0.03-0.01,0.04-0.01c1.57,1.09,2.53,2.88,2.53,4.8C34.41,38.96,31.78,41.6,28.55,41.6z"/>
 <path d="M30.76,44.45c-0.42,0.04-0.73,0.42-0.69,0.85l0.92,9.01h-5.36l0.39-9.07c0.02-0.42-0.31-0.78-0.74-0.81
  c-0.44-0.03-0.78,0.31-0.81,0.74l-0.43,9.87c-0.01,0.21,0.07,0.41,0.22,0.57c0.14,0.15,0.35,0.24,0.56,0.24h7.02
  c0.22,0,0.42-0.09,0.58-0.26c0.14-0.17,0.22-0.38,0.2-0.6l-1.01-9.87C31.56,44.71,31.17,44.4,30.76,44.45z"/>

</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: We will only be able to make guesses as to why it happens. You actually have to search for this root cause. In order to be able to help you plainly, we need you set up an [MCVE]. So keep adding whatever you have on your side until you find the culprit. Once that's done chances are you don't need us anymore, but if you do, then come and [edit] your question with all that is necessary for us to be bale to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Your code example seems to work fine. It's not like the pictures.

Comment: I think the view box causes the issue, the shadow also casts the border of the graphic

Comment: I have found out the issue, in my end, i used .shadow, which is same to bootstrap style attribute, so it triggers bootstrap as well.

Answer (score -1):

I have found out the issue! in my end, i used .shadow, which is same name as bootstrap style attribute, so it also triggers bootstrap style as well.